# Instantiate GameObject without prefabs

Tags: c#, enums, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make an inventory system for my game, however as a complete beginner, I have some questions after digging in google.

The way I design my inventory system contains 3 main class:

1. SceneItem <--- this is the gameObject in the scene
2. ItemData <--- this store all info of the item, and is put into the item class
3. InventoryHandler
4. ItemName <--- an enum that store all name of the items available

So every time my character pick up an item, the ItemData inside the SceneItem duplicate itself, and add into the list which is in the InventoryHandler, such that I can store all item's data.

Yet the problem is, if I create it this way, I afraid I will need to create a bunch of prefab, each of them contains their individual script. Which I think is not a good way to do it.

I thought the ItemName enum could help me reduce some work, by connecting the loot of the monster to the prefab's filename, but still I need to create a bunch of prefab for that

Is there anyway to get around it? Or is the way I do it just not optimal by itself?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Everything inside Unity is either Object or GameObject <- which still inherits Object. Meaning if you create a prefab or a non Prefab to instantiate it. It will still have its GameObject class and will have a Transform class inside it. What ever you do, it will contain code or scripts. A Prefab is just a set of data that will be duplicated in the process. Do not worry about making a lot of duplicate items as Unity knows how to deal with memory properly with the same Instantiated items. You don't even have to worry about properties that you will have in your classes. The only thing that you need to think about is the runtime performance not how many Scripts will be included in your single items. It may look big in your scene that you have scripts and models. But when it is compiled, it is not a big deal anymore. Garbage collection helps a lot in runtime but if you have strong references to your objects, the CLR will never know when to collect it, this is something that you would have to do for yourself.

**UPDATE**

Saying you want the XML to be a part of your solution. It is a good practice but not exactly performance wise, because you will eat up some of the run time process when you instantiate it. Every time you create the item, you will have to tell the GameEngine to look up some data on your XML model. Which is not that bad if you have a few. Remember since we the Language that we use is calculating on Runtime. It is will be slower to look up from XML, it has too be slower. But it any case your, approach is Cleaner, separation of concern and other Developer can work on the separate file of XML.

There are a lot of XML Libraries that you can use or even, why not use JSON instead as they can be both be serialized and deserialized back and forth to your model. Why did I recommend JSON? Well if you plan on using 3rd Party Unity Game API. You will end up have to use JSON instead of XML. But like I said, there is no problem Parsing XML to JSON. It is just better to start on JSON as Other UNITY Game development tools is supporting it already.

Take a look at Firebase for Unity, where you can use RealTime database for your game.
Link in here [FireBase SDK for Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uj6rs3HFg5o)

Infact you can use. FireBase Storage, if you want to save Prefab in here as well.

The solution, that you have in mind is so simple there is no way you can go wrong with it, unless you are performance savvy, But since we have a lot of gimmick to handle performance in the future like, Runtime Prefab Download. Where you can preload the game items while you are running the game. I am sure you are aware of this. Go ahead and implement the XML or as I refer the JSON file instead.

Comment: Thanks, although this didn't exactly answer my question

Comment: what's in my head now is to have prefabs that only contains an id, than the inventory will find the respective itemData in the xml database

Comment: having that said, I am still struggling with my xml lol, but I think it's a better approach

Comment: You are correct, but it is not exactly making your hard code to be reduced. Check my Updated Answer. I am not sure why you're struggling with XML a lot of Libraries is straight forward to use, why not JSON?

Comment: I actually have not realized there is something called Runtime Prefab Download... (sad face

Comment: at the moment I am trying to focus on making things work, as both me and my partner is a beginner, tho we are aiming at making something good.

Comment: As to the performance problem, can it be solved if I load all the xml data in a list, and refer to it afterwards? such that I don't need to refer to the xml everytime